# Substring function of Unicode strings by scalars

Tags: unicode, ocaml

Previously, I wrote a substring function of unicode strings over grapheme clusters as follows. The positions passed to the function were over Unicode scalars, for instance, `\r\n` is counted as 2, but Grapheme clusters count `\r\n` as 1. So this function did not work well in some cases:

```
let uni_sub (s: string) (pos: int) (len: int) = 
  let (_, r) = 
    Uuseg_string.fold_utf_8 
      `Grapheme_cluster
      (fun (p, acc) ch -> if (p >= pos) && (p <= pos+len-1) then (p+1, acc ^ ch) else (p+1, acc))
      (0, "")
      s 
    in 
  r
```

I'm suggested to write a substring function of unicode strings over their scalars, by using `Uutf.String.fold_utf_8` and `Buffer.add_utf_8_uchar`. However, without understanding well how the system works, I could only roughly write the following code and wanted to make the types work in the first place.

```
let uni_sub_scalars (s: string) (pos: int) (len: int) = 
  let b: Buffer.t = Buffer.create 42 in
  let rec add (acc: string list) (v: [ `Uchar of Stdlib.Uchar.t | `Await | `End ]) : Uuseg.ret =
    match v with
    | `Uchar u -> 
      Buffer.add_utf_8_uchar b u; 
      add acc `Await
    | `Await | `End -> failwith "don't know what to do"
  in
  let (_, r) = 
    Uuseg_string.fold_utf_8 
      (`Custom (Uuseg.custom ~add:add))
      (fun (p, acc) ch -> if (p >= pos) && (p <= pos+len-1) then (p+1, acc ^ ch) else (p+1, acc))
      (0, "")
      s 
    in 
  r
```

And the compilation returned an error that I don't know how to fix:

```
File "lib/utility.ml", line 45, characters 6-39:
45 |       (`Custom (Uuseg.custom ~add:add))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type
         [> `Custom of
              ?mandatory:(string list -> bool) ->
              name:string ->
              create:(unit -> string list) ->
              copy:(string list -> string list) -> unit -> Uuseg.custom ]
       but an expression was expected of type [< Uuseg.boundary ]
       Types for tag `Custom are incompatible
make: *** [lib/utility.cmo] Error 2
```

Could anyone help me write this substring function of Unicode strings by scalars?

Comment: You haven't fully applied the `Uuseg.custom` function. Try `Uuseg.custom ~add ()`.

Comment: It returns an error: https://ibb.co/RDjJ4MS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And the compilation returned an error that I don't know how to fix:

The `Uuseg.custom` function creates a custom segmenter and takes a few parameters (you passed only one),

```
val custom :
  ?mandatory:('a -> bool) ->
  name:string ->
  create:(unit -> 'a) ->
  copy:('a -> 'a) ->
  add: ('a -> [ `Uchar of Uchar.t | `Await | `End ] -> ret) -> unit -> custom
```

So you need to pass also the `name`, `create`, `copy` parameters as well as the positional `()` parameter. But I don't think that this is the function that you should use.

> Could anyone help me write this substring function of Unicode strings by scalars?

Yes, if we will follow the advice and implement it "by using `Uutf.String.fold_utf_8` and `Buffer.add_utf_8_uchar`", it is very easy. (Notice, that we were advised to use `Uutf.String.fold_utf_8` not `Uuseg_string.fold_utf_8`).

A simple implementation (that doesn't do a lot of error checking), will look like this,

```
let substring s pos len =
  let buf = Buffer.create len in
  let _ : int = Uutf.String.fold_utf_8 (fun off _ elt ->
      match elt with
      | `Uchar x when off >= pos && off < pos + len ->
        Buffer.add_utf_8_uchar buf x;
        off + 1
      | _ -> off + 1) 0 s in
  Buffer.contents buf
```

Here is how it works (using my name as a working example),

```
# substring "Иван\n\rГотовчиц" 0 5;;
- : string = "Иван\n"
# substring "Иван\n\rГотовчиц" 11 3;;
- : string = "чиц"
```

And it works fine with the right-to-left scripts,

```
# let shalom = substring "שָׁלוֹ";;
val shalom : int -> int -> string = <fun>
# shalom 0 1;;
- : string = "ש"
# shalom 0 2;;
- : string = "שָ"
# shalom 2 2;;
- : string = "ׁל"
# shalom 2 1;;
- : string = "ׁ"
```